# JavaScript Push function into Angular's ng-repeat array coming in blank

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Let me start by saying this is not a repeated question, I read every related question!  My edit functions work fine, and my push function to update the array was working, and I'm certain I never touched it, it just stopped working!

I'm going to say my HTML form has ng-model's that have no spelling errors, that are used to help with the push.  The Angular code:

```
                $scope.add = function(id){

                $scope.people.push({
                name: $scope.name, 
                phone1: $scope.phone1, 
                phone2: $scope.phone2,
                phone3: $scope.phone3,  
                email: $scope.email, 
                city: $scope.city,
                state: $scope.state    
            });
        //More code here that resets the forms input//
    }
```

My edit functions work, my delete ones do, it's just this one, when I hit the button that sets off the add() function, it resets the form input, but pushes a blank array into my ng-repeat list!

I have a form that has multiple inputs with ng-model set to whatever; name, phone1 ... etc, and the angular code is correct, so why the hell will this not work?

```
<div class="centered" ng-show="addcont">
            <form id="adder" name="commentForm" method="post">
            <h2 class="formtitle">Add Contact</h2>
                <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
                <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>
                <input class="edit" type="text" ng-model="name">
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td>
                <input class="edit" type="text" ng-model="email">
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Phone</td>
                <td>
                <input type="text" id="number" class="edit" maxlength="3" size="3" ng-model="phone1">
                <input type="text" id="number" class="edit" maxlength="3" size="3" ng-model="phone2" /> -
                <input type="text" id="number" class="edit" maxlength="4" size="5" ng-model="phone3" />
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>City</td>
                <td>
                <input class="edit" type="text" ng-model="city">
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>State</td>
                <td>
                <input class="edit" type="text" ng-model="state">
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                <input type="button" value="Save" ng-click="add();                                                                                            `showAdd()">
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                </form>
            </div>
```

MAJOR UPDATE!

I use a JQuery autotab function, and as soon as I commented it out, the arrays passed in normally again.
The function is used on the form provided above, and auto tabs to the next input.

Here's the function:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.edit').autotab();
 });
</script>
```

Comment: What happens if you don't reset it below this line?

Comment: I commented out the reset code, didn't change the ineffectivity

Comment: Could you do a fiddle ?

Comment: who are you resetting the form? Please add that code too

Comment: This is similar code I pulled off the internet thats doing what I'm doing in a smaller app:

Comment: $scope.addTodo = function() {
    $scope.todos.push({
    text:$scope.todoText, 
    done:false
    });
    
    $scope.todoText = '';
  };

Comment: I'm resetting it so when I go to add a second Item the form isn't pre-filled out

Comment: @Adrian, try resetting like `$scope.people = {}` after the push is completed.

Comment: The resetting isn't the issue.  As stated before, I removed that code before hand leaving only the push and the push still wasn't working.

Comment: The codes flawless, I've done this pleanty of times, it's driving me insane

Comment: Please paste your form

Comment: have you initialized `$scope.people = []` in your controller first?

Comment: Yes.  Theres like 30 other functions that work fine in this controller with the .people array.  Only other issue is the edit function only allows me to delete letters and numbers, and when I add new ones to the edited piece, it comes blank as well

Comment: The form I posted incorrectly, it shows the "add()" function incompletely, but its there aswell.

Comment: @Sravan please look at the update on the question

Comment: In jquery `auto-tab` there is an angular version refer to this file,
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Mathachew/jquery-autotab/master/angular.html

Comment: or do one thing, add `$('.edit').autotab();` in your controller at the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using Jquery and angular doestnot fit every time**

So, we should use the angular version of the Auto tabs.

So, Here is the solved example using **Auto tabs with Angular**.

The important line to be added is

`$.autotab.selectFilterByClass = true;`

```js
    $.autotab.selectFilterByClass = true;
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    //$('.edit').autotab();
    $.autotab.refresh();
    $scope.people = [];
        $scope.add = function(id){
            $scope.people.push({
            name: $scope.name, 
            phone1: $scope.phone1, 
            phone2: $scope.phone2,
            phone3: $scope.phone3,  
            email: $scope.email, 
            city: $scope.city,
            state: $scope.state    
        });
            setTimeout(function () {
                $.autotab.refresh();
            }, 1);
    //More code here that resets the forms input//
        }
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-autotab/1.9.2/js/jquery.autotab.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div class="centered">
    <form id="adder" name="commentForm" method="post">
    <h2 class="formtitle">Add Contact</h2>
    {{people}}
        <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
        <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>
        <input class="edit" type="text" ng-model="name">
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td>
        <input class="edit" type="text" ng-model="email">
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Phone</td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" id="number" class="edit number" maxlength="3" size="3" ng-model="phone1">
        <input type="text" id="number" class="edit number" maxlength="3" size="3" ng-model="phone2" /> -
        <input type="text" id="number" class="edit number" maxlength="4" size="5" ng-model="phone3" />
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>City</td>
        <td>
        <input class="edit" type="text" ng-model="city">
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>State</td>
        <td>
        <input class="edit" type="text" ng-model="state">
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
        <input type="button" value="Save" ng-click="add()">
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
    </div>



</div>

  
</body>
</html>
```

**Please run the Above SNIPPET**

Now, your pushing the code into the Array works fine with **AUTO-TAB**.

[**HERE IS A WORKING DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/hwoo2q1e20lfZYn1AGYT?p=preview)

Comment: @Adrian Higgins, please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to push the variables by value and not by reference. The quickest solution that I came through is using the JSON object. This might be a problem when you reset the $scope.name for example, it updates the value in your array.

```
$scope.add = function(id){
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.people.push({
            name: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($scope.name)), 
            phone1: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($scope.phone1)), 
            ...
        });
    });
    //other code
}
```

Comment: I don't think so! You can try other functions too that assigns the value and not the reference in javascript

Comment: Yea this still isn't working for me...infact weirdly it made a totally different function stop working (A function that shares the save button that closes the form)

Comment: OK strange. Can you share a fiddle link with just relevant information?

Comment: Please look at the most recent update in the question, I found the problem, don;t know what causes the conflict